# Xcode 4.4.1: how to disable auto commit for several changed projects?

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

Does anybody is facing a weird svn auto commit behavior in xcode 4.4.1? Have noticed, if working with several projects at the same time and you are doing svn commit then Xcode grabs all changes from several projects and tries to commit them all. It very annoys me as it's very easy to commit unfinished changes accidentally, because Xcode svn commit opens a tab where only changes of active project are shown. Is there a preference setting for disabling this?